# pass traffic between private and and public subnet by Nat Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat

is it possible to pass traffic between one resource in private subnet and another one in public subnet? 
for example; the caching servers in front of NLB. the NLB is in public subnet and the cache instances are in private subnet with NAT gateway.

Answer (score 0):

All resources within the same AWS VPC can communicate with each other. It doesn't matter if some of them are Public or Private subnets, they can all communicate with each other.

You should use the **private IP address** to communicate with another resource in the same VPC.